# Pixel to world coordinate conversion

Tags: python, opencv, transformation, image-manipulation

I am trying to convert 2d pixel points to 3d points in python.
I have the intrinsic camera matrix-like focal point, the center of the image. But I don't know what should I do next And how should I go ahead. Kindly help.

Comment: every pixel point corresponds to a full ray of 3d position, so you will need additional information (like a distance value) or assumptions to estimate a 3d information from a pixel + camera intrinsics + camera extrinsics

Comment: Hi @Micka, Can you make it more clear or share any references?